# Google Drive File Download Through Picker Always Returns File Not Found

Tags: javascript, php, google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I've now spent hours making this work and I'm running out of documentation to read on how to get such a simple process to work correctly. Here's my ideal situation.

I have a javascript version of the Google Drive picker (too me a couple hours to finally figured out the thing that I wanted google called the Google Picker API). Once I found it, it works like a charm and everything I ever hoped it would be. (kinda). What I need to have happen is the picker returns the file_id (which it does) and then I use that file ID in a php script to fetch the file through a wget call and then I save the file on my server. I haven't been able to get a curl request to work right so I used googles php library, which I'd rather not use, but whatever will make it work.

My glaringly huge problem is I have tried through the javascript api and the php api and even google's own explorer api and I get a file not found error on any file I choose from the several different google drive accounts I've attempted. I've been able to fix the myriad of descriptive (or lack thereof) errors and I'm finally settling down to this one error I cannot get passed. The javascript api returns a error 400 "Required Value: id" even though I know the value is getting populated correctly. The php library returns an error 404: File Not Found

I have Google Drive API enabled and running. I have Google Drive SDK enabled and appears to be working properly. I've read elsewhere that this could be a file permissions error, but I have no direction on how to correct this if it even is the problem.

For the record, I also had to do a dropbox integration, and entire integration from start to finish was less than 30 minutes.

### Edit

Just in case I'm missing something with my api keys (there are way too many), for the picker, I need to the following from the Google Cloud interface. The .setDeveloperKey which is the Browser Key API Key, the .setAppId is the Oauth 2.0 client id.

When I setup the php library and am building up the client, $client->setClientId() is my Oauth 2.0 client id and $client->setDeveloperKey() is my Server Key API Key correct?

Comment: It would help if you could post the http requests and responses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to authorize and authenticate your requests on the behalf of the user, a key and your client ID will not be enough to access user's non-public document. Auth for PHP is explained on https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-php

Comment: I've been reading more and more documentation and after borrowing code from 3-4 different pages and multiple google searches I've finally put together something that returns the file metadata. Just because of how my current process is, it'd be nice to save the access_token and downloadUrl to a form input and pass that through a form upload script and then have curl pull the file from the url while setting the header to "Authorization: Bearer {$_POST access_token}". I did this and I got a full on file with the content being a google web page saying I need to clear my cache/cookies

Comment: btw I'm using the Javascript API

Comment: And suddenly my next request worked correctly and returned the document and not the google weird page. Thanks for your help.....sooooooo much work for such a simple process. :(

Answer (score 1):

In my case it turned out to be a problem with scopes. When I used `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file'` I got 404 for any file. However when I used `'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly'`, I can get the meta data and exportLink for downloading file contents, etc.

Per https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes, the 'file' scope gives access to files **created or opened by the app**, while the 'readonly' scope does not have this constraint.